# VBA Nested IF compare statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi I am newbies about vba. I want to compare and count the cell number that continuously lowers the previous cell however the code just successfully counts 1-2 days and n/a only.

Thanks

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNLxC.png)

```
  Sub Mars()
   Dim i As Integer
   Sheets("working").Select
   For i = 2 To 111
       If Range("U" & i).Value > Range("T" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "n/a"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "1"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "2"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "3"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "4"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "5"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "6"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "7"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "8"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "9"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "10"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "11"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "12"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "13"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "14"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value < Range("F" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "15"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value < Range("F" & i).Value < Range("E" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "16"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value < Range("F" & i).Value < Range("E" & i).Value < Range("D" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "17"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value < Range("F" & i).Value < Range("E" & i).Value < Range("D" & i).Value < Range("C" & i).Value Then
            Range("W" & i).Value = "18"
       ElseIf Range("U" & i).Value < Range("T" & i).Value < Range("S" & i).Value < Range("R" & i).Value < Range("Q" & i).Value < Range("P" & i).Value < Range("O" & i).Value < Range("N" & i).Value < Range("M" & i) < Range("L" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value < Range("J" & i).Value < Range("I" & i).Value < Range("H" & i).Value < Range("G" & i).Value < Range("F" & i).Value < Range("E" & i).Value < Range("D" & i).Value < Range("C" & i).Value < Range("B" & i).Value Then
           Range("W" & i).Value = "19"
       End If
   Next I
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the're a lot of this construction:

```
IF A < B < C < ...
```

This is not correct, it should be:

```
IF (A < B) AND (B < C) AND (C < ...) ...
```

For readability reasons, I would advise you the following formatting:

```
IF (A < B) AND_
   (B < C) AND_
   (C < ...) ...
```

(The underscore means that the "source code line" is not finished and continues on the next line.)